# Can I get or make a stock Netgear firmware image for flashing with tftp?

Tags: router, firmware

I have a Netgear WN604 access point and I would like to flash stock firmware to it using its TFTP recovery mode. The firmwares are provided by Netgear as zip files containing embedded tar files, whereas the tftp upload requires an image file.

The tftp recovery mode is accessed by powering on with RESET applied and held until the "Upgrade Mode" prompt appears on the serial console. The firmware is then applied from a computer with `tftp`:

```
$ tftp 192.168.1.1
tftp> binary
tftp> put wn604_firmware.bin
```

If there is a method to take the ZIP, the TAR embedded within the ZIP, or the files embedded within the TAR and convert them into an image file format suitable for uploading using the above method then that would be fine. Otherwise a download source for the pre-prepared image.

The Netgear web interface cannot be used because the device has OpenWrt on it.

Can I get or make a stock Netgear firmware image for flashing with tftp ?

Comment: If you have OpenWRT why can't you just upload the stock firmware, which is what you typically would do, when you want to revert back to the OEM firmware when your using OpenWRT

Comment: Perhaps I can, but I'd like to be able to do it using a vendor firmware across the `tftp` mechanism described above because it does not depend on a working operating system (such as after bricking OpenWrt).